# hide column using select case when field values from other table is not equal

Tags: sql-server

I have two the same tables. I have to compare their field name values and select the column with different value. Fields with null or not equal values should be hidden.

Im using select case for the value comparisson, is there any possible query to hide columns?

thanks .

Comment: No not without dynamic sql

Comment: How is this related to `vb.net`?